# Cucumber JUnit tests not gluing feature to stepdefinitions

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have setup a cucumber project in java, in my Eclipse IDE I am able to run my feature file directly and the tests will complete. However when I run them as JUnit tests they don't run, in the console they appear as

```
@When("^user navigates to Login Page$")
public void user_navigates_to_Login_Page() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

and if I double click the step in the JUnit tab I get the following message

"Test class not found in selected Project"

My test runner class looks like this,

```
package com.bsautoweb.runner;

import java.io.File;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import com.cucumber.listener.Reporter;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(glue = {"src/test/java/com/bsautoweb/stepdefinitions"}, features = {"src/test/resources/features/"},
plugin = "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/cucumber-reports/report.html",
monochrome = true
)

public class Testrunner {
    @AfterClass
    public static void writeExtentReport() {
        Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("config/report.xml"));

    }
}
```

My folder structure looks like this

[image: folder structure]

It seems that JUnit is ignoring my glue code. Even if I enter an invalid path, it doesn't complain.

Comment: Set the glue option as `com/bsautoweb/stepdefinitions`

Comment: Hi, this worked for me thanks, If you want to make an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the glue option as `com/bsautoweb/stepdefinitions` or as java package style `com.bsautoweb.stepdefinitions`

Comment: This is the correct answer. Java package style is maybe a little better as it reinforces that it's not a folder in the project, but a namespace.

Answer (score -2):

Give glue = "com.bsautoweb.stepdefinitions"